# How could i use refresh token to get new access token in docusign

Tags: docusignapi

From the authentication i got the access token and refresh token but access token will expire in 8 hours after that i need to use the services, please suggest here how could i go for. Is there any way to increase the access token expiry time from 8 to N.

Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you obtain the extended scope a refresh token will typically last 30 days. Please have a look [here](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/authcode/authcode-get-token/) for more information: